# How to know if the monitor is in secondary or tertiary display?

Tags: x11, display, xrandr, display-settings

Having an example using `xrandr --listmonitors` shows the outputs below.

How do to know if the monitor labeled `1 DisplayPort-3` is in secondary or third? Likewise for the monitor labeled `2 HDMI-A-0`. We know that DisplayPort-4 is primary because of the `*` mark and also by using `--query` will show keyword "connected primary".

```
0: +*DisplayPort-4 1920/518x1200/324+1920+0  DisplayPort-4
1: +DisplayPort-3 1920/518x1200/324+0+0  DisplayPort-3
2: +HDMI-A-0 1920/518x1200/324+3840+0  HDMI-A-0
```

I'm new to linux and I wanted to know how to query the monitors in secondary and third display. I don't know how. If there's a utility or simple file locations or system commands to query it that would be great. I only find the xrandr tool but not sure if it can get secondary and third display.